# How to set Image View as canvas and draw on that canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have many images which I set on imageView by clicking on a Button, I want to create a class of Drawing so that when the image is on ImageView I can paint on it, and after clicking on the button I will be able to drawing on the new image.
Till now I have this. Please help me to do this I am new in programming I don't know much. Just a little about OOP and DS.

```
public class EnglishDrawing extends Activity{
private int currentImage = 0;
private ImageView changeImageView;
private Button changeImageOnClick;
private Button changePreviousImageOnClick;
public Bitmap mybitmap,newbmp,bitmap,bmp;
int image[] = { R.drawable.englishdot_01, R.drawable.englishdot_02,
        R.drawable.englishdot_03, R.drawable.englishdot_04,
        R.drawable.englishdot_05, R.drawable.englishdot_06,R.drawable.englishdot_07,
        R.drawable.englishdot_08,
        R.drawable.englishdot_09,
        R.drawable.englishdot_10,
        R.drawable.englishdot_11,
        R.drawable.englishdot_12,
        R.drawable.englishdot_13,
        R.drawable.englishdot_14,
        R.drawable.englishdot_15,
        R.drawable.englishdot_16,
        R.drawable.englishdot_17,
        R.drawable.englishdot_18,
        R.drawable.englishdot_19,
        R.drawable.englishdot_20,
        R.drawable.englishdot_21,
        R.drawable.englishdot_22,
        R.drawable.englishdot_23,
        R.drawable.englishdot_24,
        R.drawable.englishdot_25,
        R.drawable.englishdot_26

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.englishdrawing);
    changeImageOnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextDrawEng);
    changePreviousImageOnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preDrawEng);
    changeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.englishdrawingimageview);
    changeImageOnClick.setOnClickListener(aButtonChangeImageListener);
    changePreviousImageOnClick.setOnClickListener(bButtonOnClickListener);
    changeImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}
View.OnClickListener aButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentImage++;
        currentImage = currentImage % image.length;
        changeImageView.setImageResource(image[currentImage]);
    }
};
View.OnClickListener bButtonOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentImage--;
        currentImage = (currentImage + image.length) % image.length;
        changeImageView.setImageResource(image[currentImage]);

    }
};

}
```

Comment: Its not possible to set imageview as canvas.Instead you should use canvas as imageview and draw the imageview on cavas

Comment: then how i'll change my images..??

Comment: I have the same problem Is there any help to draw any drawable images on the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your image as bitmap:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.your_image);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap , 0,0, null);
```

You then can draw on the canvas.
On click of canvas you get the next image as bitmap just like above and again draw it on canvas.This is how you can draw on image also..!

Comment: It was nice but I think you didn't get what I want to say, I want to create a class and do that procedure inside a constructor so when object change the object of that class create new painting.

Comment: Yes You can do that..! create new canvas for it or clear the canvas..am i right?